# Can't enable kie-drools-wb-7.10.0.war in wildfly 11 after deployment

Tags: optaplanner, wildfly-11, kie-wb

I went  through the installation guide on https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.10.0.Final/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single/#_planner.quickstart and on https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single/#_wildfly_11_x and did the steps desciped there but I can't enable the kie-wb deployment. I tried to install the kie-wb by copying it in the /standalone/deployments and by adding the kie-wb.war from the wildfly deployments GUI.

I start wildfly with

> ./bin/standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml -Dorg.kie.server.user=planner -Dorg.kie.server.pwd=Planner123_ -Dorg.kie.server.controller.user=planner -Dorg.kie.server.controller.pwd=Planner123_ -Dorg.kie.server.id=wildfly-kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller

In the second case I get this errors:

> 15:38:35,251 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Found kmodule: vfs:/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-wb-common-services-backend-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,273 ERROR [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error when reading virtual file from vfs:/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-wb-common-services-backend-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance
>   of declaring class
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.getPathForVFS(ClasspathKieProject.java:423)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fixURLFromKProjectPath(ClasspathKieProject.java:368)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:141)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.discoverKieModules(ClasspathKieProject.java:112)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.init(ClasspathKieProject.java:84)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.(KieContainerImpl.java:131)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:131)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:118)
>           at org.drools.cdi.KieCDIExtension.init(KieCDIExtension.java:94)
>           at org.drools.cdi.KieCDIExtension.processInjectionTarget(KieCDIExtension.java:100)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
>           at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
>           at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
>           at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:124)
>           at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.fire(AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.java:33)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessInjectionTarget(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:269)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.processInjectionTargetEvents(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:140)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processBeans(BeanDeployer.java:262)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processClassBeanAttributes(BeanDeployer.java:244)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:436)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:86)
>           at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:97)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
>           at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   15:38:35,884 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to find pom.properties in /content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-wb-common-services-backend-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,885 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to find pom.properties in /content/kie-wb.war
>   15:38:35,885 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) As folder project tried to fall back to pom.xml, but could not find one
>   15:38:35,886 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to load pom.properties from/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-wb-common-services-backend-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,886 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Cannot find maven pom properties for this project. Using the container's default ReleaseId
>   15:38:35,898 ERROR [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=vfs:/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-wb-common-services-backend-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   Unable to get all ZipFile entries: /content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-wb-common-services-backend-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,898 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Found kmodule: vfs:/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-dmn-validation-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,899 ERROR [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error when reading virtual file from vfs:/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-dmn-validation-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.getPathForVFS(ClasspathKieProject.java:423)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fixURLFromKProjectPath(ClasspathKieProject.java:368)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:141)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.discoverKieModules(ClasspathKieProject.java:112)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.init(ClasspathKieProject.java:84)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.(KieContainerImpl.java:131)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:131)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:118)
>           at org.drools.cdi.KieCDIExtension.init(KieCDIExtension.java:94)
>           at org.drools.cdi.KieCDIExtension.processInjectionTarget(KieCDIExtension.java:100)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
>           at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
>           at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
>           at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:124)
>           at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.fire(AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.java:33)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessInjectionTarget(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:269)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.processInjectionTargetEvents(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:140)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processBeans(BeanDeployer.java:262)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processClassBeanAttributes(BeanDeployer.java:244)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:436)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:86)
>           at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:97)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
>           at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   15:38:35,927 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to find pom.properties in /content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-dmn-validation-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,928 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to find pom.properties in /content/kie-wb.war
>   15:38:35,928 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) As folder project tried to fall back to pom.xml, but could not find one
>   15:38:35,928 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to load pom.properties from/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-dmn-validation-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,929 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Cannot find maven pom properties for this project. Using the container's default ReleaseId
>   15:38:35,930 ERROR [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=vfs:/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-dmn-validation-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   Unable to get all ZipFile entries: /content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-dmn-validation-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,930 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Found kmodule: vfs:/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-pmml-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,931 ERROR [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error when reading virtual file from vfs:/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-pmml-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.getPathForVFS(ClasspathKieProject.java:423)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fixURLFromKProjectPath(ClasspathKieProject.java:368)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:141)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.discoverKieModules(ClasspathKieProject.java:112)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.init(ClasspathKieProject.java:84)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.(KieContainerImpl.java:131)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:131)
>           at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:118)
>           at org.drools.cdi.KieCDIExtension.init(KieCDIExtension.java:94)
>           at org.drools.cdi.KieCDIExtension.processInjectionTarget(KieCDIExtension.java:100)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
>           at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
>           at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
>           at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:124)
>           at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
>           at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.fire(AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.java:33)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessInjectionTarget(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:269)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.processInjectionTargetEvents(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:140)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processBeans(BeanDeployer.java:262)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processClassBeanAttributes(BeanDeployer.java:244)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:436)
>           at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:86)
>           at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:97)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
>           at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   15:38:35,995 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to find pom.properties in /content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-pmml-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,998 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to find pom.properties in /content/kie-wb.war
>   15:38:35,999 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) As folder project tried to fall back to pom.xml, but could not find one
>   15:38:35,999 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to load pom.properties from/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-pmml-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:35,999 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Cannot find maven pom properties for this project. Using the container's default ReleaseId
>   15:38:36,000 ERROR [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=vfs:/content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-pmml-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   Unable to get all ZipFile entries: /content/kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/lib/kie-pmml-7.11.0.Final.jar/META-INF/kmodule.xml
>   15:38:37,640 INFO  [org.jboss.errai.common.metadata.MetaDataScanner] (Thread-112) added class scanning extensions: org.jboss.errai.common.metadata.JbossVFsTypeHandler
>   15:38:37,641 INFO  [org.jboss.errai.common.metadata.MetaDataScanner] (Thread-112) added class scanning extensions: org.jboss.errai.common.metadata.JbossVFsTypeHandler
>   15:40:11,831 INFO  [org.jboss.errai.reflections.Reflections] (Thread-112) Reflections took 94179 ms to scan 152 urls, producing 4832 keys and 32877 values [using 2 cores]
>   15:40:12,062 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil] (MSC service thread 1-4) The property errai.security.user_on_hostpage_enabled has been set multiple times.
>   15:40:12,084 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil] (MSC service thread 1-4) The property errai.class_scanning_extension has been set multiple times.
>   15:40:32,658 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.kie.workbench.common.forms.data.modeller.service.DataObjectFinderService
>   15:40:32,660 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.uberfire.preferences.shared.PreferenceStorage
>   15:40:32,664 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.guvnor.common.services.project.service.ModuleService
>   15:40:32,675 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.guvnor.common.services.project.service.ModuleRepositoriesService
>   15:40:32,687 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.guvnor.common.services.shared.metadata.MetadataService
>   15:40:32,708 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.kie.workbench.common.forms.data.modeller.service.DataObjectFormModelCreationService
>   15:40:32,740 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.kie.workbench.common.stunner.core.service.DiagramLookupService
>   15:40:32,742 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.optaplanner.workbench.screens.guidedrule.service.ScoreHolderService
>   15:40:32,749 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.drools.workbench.screens.guided.dtable.service.GuidedDecisionTableGraphSaveAndRenameService
>   15:40:32,777 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.guvnor.common.services.project.service.WorkspaceProjectService
>   15:40:32,799 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.kie.workbench.common.forms.editor.service.FormCreatorService
>   15:40:32,800 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints] (MSC service thread 1-4) No @Service implementations found for org.uberfire.ext.editor.commons.service.htmleditor.HtmlEditorService
>   15:42:13,483 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "kie-wb.war")]'
>   15:42:35,526 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "kie-wb.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: "WFLYCTL0344: Operation timed out awaiting service container stability"
>   15:42:47,036 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentHandlerUtil$1@1dae869d for operation deploy at address [("deployment" => "kie-wb.war")] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:521)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1518)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1472)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1445)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1319)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:876)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:726)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1411)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:423)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$execute$1(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
>           at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:265)
>           at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:231)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
>           at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:212)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
>           at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:93)
>           at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:62)
>           at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:289)
>           at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:246)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
>           at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.handleRequest(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
>           at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
>           at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>           at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>           at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>           at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
>   15:43:06,915 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentHandlerUtil$1@1dae869d for operation deploy at address [("deployment" => "kie-wb.war")] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>   15:43:38,794 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0349: Timeout after [5] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation. Process must be restarted. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "kie-wb.war")]'

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kie-wb doesn't work with Oracle Java. I could deploy kie-wb in wildfly after I removed Oracle Java and installed openJDK.